# can require_once() be called in the middle of php execution?

Tags: php, file

I want to write a script that creates a PHP file with some definitions (`define(..., ...);`) and then within this script i want to run more commands that uses the definitions i just defined in the newly created php file. for this to work i am guessing i could do something like that :

1. create file (say `def.php`) and write `definitions` to it
2. require_once '`def.php`';
3. run commands that uses definitions from `def.php`

will this work? if not what is the right way of doing it?

Comment: It works, but it seems a bit weird to me (writing definitions to a file and then include it). Why are you doing this?

Comment: You can use `require()`/`require_once()` anywhere in your script. Remember that if it fails, the rest of the script won't be executed.

Comment: Why not just set variables and use those instead? No read/write needed, easier to code, easier to debug & easier to read.

Comment: @jite, these definitions are to be used from a lot of other scripts too

Comment: Sessions? Database? Textfile? Is a generated php file with define() calls really a good idea? :P

Comment: @OfekRon Well, it much depends on what you will be putting in the file. It could be a potential security hole. I just don't see any possible scenario where I myself would use a solution like this. But then again, I don't know what you are trying to do, might be super logical if I did :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **will** work, you can use it but if the file does not exist then it will call `exit()` in the middle of your page so you will get a half loaded page with an error message.

Comment: the file wont pre-exist, it will only be created after the first section of the script, right before the require line invoked, will it still work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `eval()` or anonymous functions (closures) should be better.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php
http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php